# How to send a hexadecimal message using u-blox SARA-R422M10S module

Tags: c, amazon-ec2, iot, aws-iot

I'm currently working with the u-blox SARA-R422M10S module, and I've successfully implemented a command for sending ASCII text messages over a TCP socket. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```cpp
if (binary_mode_enabled) {
    ECHO("binary mode");
    command = "AT+USOWR=" + socket_id + "," + echo_text.length()/2;
    SENDAT(command, waiting_time_at, "@");
    SENDAT(echo_text, waiting_time_at, "OK");

    WAIT("+UUSORD", waiting_timeout);

    command = "AT+USORD=" + socket_id + "," + echo_text.length();
    returned_echo = SENDAT(command, waiting_time_at, "OK");
    ECHO(returned_echo);
}
```

This code works well for sending ASCII messages. However, I need to send a message in hexadecimal format. I have already converted my message to a hexadecimal string using `STRING2HEX(echo_text)`, but I'm unsure how to modify the code to send this hexadecimal message over the TCP socket.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to send a hexadecimal message using the u-blox SARA-R422M10S module in binary mode?

Thank you for your assistance.

I have already attempted to modify the code to send the hexadecimal message by converting my ASCII text to hexadecimal using the STRING2HEX function. Here's the modified code snippet:

Comment: Where_'s the modified code snippet_?